# I have 2 lists as shown. How do i divide all the elements of list_A by list_B?

Tags: python

this is the input:
`list_A = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]`

`list_B = [5, 6, 6, 5]`

I want the following output:

`expected_output = [[1/5, 1/5, 1/5, 1/5, 1/5], [1/6, 2/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6], [1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6], [1/5, 1/5, 1/5, 1/5, 1/5]]`

Comment: basically trying to find term frequency.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

```
list(list(map(lambda x: x/b, a)) for a, b in zip(list_A, list_B))
```

Output:

```
[[0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2], [0.16666666666666666, 0.3333333333333333, 0.16666666666666666, 0.16666666666666666, 0.16666666666666666], [0.16666666666666666, 0.16666666666666666, 0.16666666666666666, 0.16666666666666666, 0.16666666666666666, 0.16666666666666666], [0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Using a for loop:

```
list_A = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
list_B = [5, 6, 6, 5]
expected_output = []

for idx, nums in enumerate(list_A):
   output_list = []
   for num in nums:
       output_list.append(num / list_B[idx])
   expected_output.append(output_list)
```

## Using list comprehension:

```
expected_output = [[num / list_B[idx] for num in nums] for idx, nums in enumerate(list_A)]
```

## Output:

```
>> print(expected_output)
[[0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2], 
[0.16666666666666666, 0.3333333333333333, 0.16666666666666666, 0.16666666666666666, 0.16666666666666666], [0.16666666666666666, 0.16666666666666666, 0.16666666666666666, 0.16666666666666666, 0.16666666666666666, 0.16666666666666666], 
[0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried something like this:

```
list_A = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
list_B = [5, 6, 6, 5]

for i in range(len(list_B)):
    list_A[i] = [x/list_B[i] for x in list_A[i]]
print(list_A)
```